# Close activity or call finish() from class that extends ContextWrapper

Tags: java, android

I have one activity with viewPager. Suppose `Post_Home` is my `activity` that extends `AppCompatActivity`. And I have another class `Post__Home` that extends `ContextWrapper`.

My Post__Home Class:

```
public class Post__Home extends ContextWrapper {

    public Post__Home(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

public void DoSomething(){
if(someValueisOK){
 // I Need to close the main activity (i.e. Post_Home) from this method.
}
}
}
```

My Post_Home class

```
public class Post_Home extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post_home);            
       init();
    }

//I have a reference of the Post__Home class something like this:
 private void init(){
   Post__Home home = new Post__Home(this);
   home.DoSomething();
 }
}
```

How can I call `finish()` method in `home.DoSomething()` ? Or is there any way by which I can close the `Post_Home` and open some other `activity`?

Answer (score 0):

You could call  `((Post_Home)context).finish();`

Comment: How can I get the `context` ? Should I use `context` reference in my class in stead of `this` ?

Comment: You can create a class variable as suggested by Marcos

Answer (score 0):

Assign the Parameter context from your Post_Home to a field and use it to call finish.

```
public class PostHomeCtx extends ContextWrapper {
    private final Activity activity;
    public PostHomeCtx(Activity context){
        super(context);
        activity = context;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        if(someValueisOK)
            acivity.finish();
    }
}
```

And please dont add those underlines on class nameses and Uppercase on first letter of methods